# ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running:

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ssh

I obtain this error when I run my python scripts using ssh in a remote server after some time.

I solved partially importing:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
```

The problem is after sometime I need to restart my connection via ssh because I obtain
"ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running".

Is there a way to avoid to exit and re-login every time that the error appears?